# Is there a script to convert an XML file to Excel that doesn't use PHP nor Excel's Import Data?

Tags: python, excel, xml, csv

Python has been attempted with the following code but output data in XLS or CSV is not the same as the data observed in the XML (via XML Notepad). Any support on this would be appreciated ... thanks:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET import pandas as pd

def parse_interval_reading(reading):
    return {
        'duration': reading.find('{http://test.test}timePeriod/{http://test.test}duration').text,
        'start': reading.find('{http://test.test}timePeriod/{http://test.test}start').text,
        'value': reading.find('{http://test.test}value').text,
    } def green_button_xml_to_df(xml_file):
    tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    root = tree.getroot()

    readings = root.findall('.//{http://test.test}IntervalReading')

    data = [parse_interval_reading(reading) for reading in readings]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'], unit='s')

    return df

def convert_green_button_xml_to_csv(xml_file, csv_file):
    df = green_button_xml_to_df(xml_file)
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)

convert_test_xml_to_csv('/Users/dummyname/Downloads/test.xml',
'/Users/dummyname/output.csv’)
```

Comment: I think there are quite a few examples on the web. what is your point about php?

Comment: You can use pandas [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: You can use a powershell script.

Comment: How exactly does the CSV differ? Please edit your question to include a representative sample of the XML and the expected CSV (doesn't need to be literal if there's confidential info).

Answer (score 0):

Like you've started with, you can use Python's standard etree module, along with the standard csv module, to get a fairly simple program that can read XML like this:

```xml
<root xmlns:test="http://test.test">
    <test:IntervalReading>
        <test:timePeriod>
            <test:duration>Dur A</test:duration>
            <test:start>Start A</test:start>
        </test:timePeriod>
        <test:value>Value A</test:value>
    </test:IntervalReading>
    <test:IntervalReading>
        <test:timePeriod>
            <test:duration>Dur B</test:duration>
            <test:start>Start B</test:start>
        </test:timePeriod>
        <test:value>Value B</test:value>
    </test:IntervalReading>
</root>
```

and produce CSV like this:

```
| interval | duration | start   | value   |
|----------|----------|---------|---------|
| 1        | Dur A    | Start A | Value A |
| 2        | Dur B    | Start B | Value B |
```

When dealing with XML that has namespaces, [declaring your namespaces ahead of time in a dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces) and referencing that dict in all the calls to find/findall can save a lot of clutter, e.g.,:

```py
ns = {"t": "http://test.test"}

intervals = root.findall(".//t:IntervalReading", ns)
...
interval.find("t:timePeriod", ns)
```

findall and find will look for the `t` key in the provided dict `ns` then use the URL-value for all node evaluations.

Note that `t` in the dict is different from the literal prefix `test` in the XML source (I showed above).  You could also have chosen the key `FooBar` for the `ns` dict, then referenced it in your paths like:

```py
intervals = root.findall(".//FooBar:IntervalReading", ns)
...
interval.find("FooBar:timePeriod", ns)
```

To avoid pandas (which seems, to me, to be too much for this use case) you can use the [DictWriter from the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) to turn a list of dicts into a CSV.  This will work well with the approach you already started of converting each interval to a dict:

```py
rows: list[dict[str, str]] = []
...
   rows.append(
        {
            "duration": dur,
            "start": start,
            "value": value,
        }
    )
...
```

The DictWriter needs to know the fieldnames it will be looking for in the dicts, so I passed in the first row (it knows to read the keys of the dict) then call the writer's writeheader method before writing all the rows:

```py
...
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=row[0])
writer.writeheader()
write.writerows(rows)
```

I like type-hinting and pre-declaring my list and dict types and running Pylance, and the find method and text property of an ET.Element can return None, so the following code has a lot None-checks that you can leave out:

```py
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = {"t": "http://test.test"}

root = ET.parse("input.xml")

intervals = root.findall(".//t:IntervalReading", ns)
if not intervals:
    print("error: no intervals found; check namespace/prefix and path")
    exit(1)

rows: list[dict[str, str]] = []
for i, interval in enumerate(intervals, start=1):
    value = ""
    e = interval.find("t:value", ns)
    if e is not None and e.text is not None:
        value = e.text

    dur = ""
    start = ""
    tp = interval.find("t:timePeriod", ns)
    if tp is not None:
        e = tp.find("t:duration", ns)
        if e is not None and e.text is not None:
            dur = e.text

        e = tp.find("t:start", ns)
        if e is not None and e.text is not None:
            start = e.text

    rows.append(
        {
            "interval": str(i),
            "duration": dur,
            "start": start,
            "value": value,
        }
    )


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=rows[0])
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```